# SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax in math.sqrt in Python

Tags: python-3.x, import, syntax-error, math.sqrt

I tried this

```
import math
from math import sqrt
def euclideanDistance(xtr, ytr, Ltr):
 distance = 0
 for x in range(Ltr):
    distance += pow((xtr[x] - ytr[x]), 2)
return sqrt(distance)
```

But it returned me the following error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 5
    return sqrt(distance)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the cause of this syntax error?

Comment: @anil: Please don't change the indentation of Python questions. Frequently (such as in this case), the indentation is the cause of the error.

Comment: @user2357112 , I realized that. Thanks for pointing out. In my answer, that's why I mentioned specifically that I considered code in the picture attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the picture you have attached, The problem is with the return statement indentation. The following is the correct indentation.

```
from math import sqrt;
def euclideanDistance(xtr, ytr, Ltr):
    distance = 0
    for x in range(Ltr):
        distance += pow((xtr[x] - ytr[x]), 2)
    return sqrt(distance)
```

Above code ran without any errors.